# Background color and background in one time

Tags: css

Is it possible to use background and background-color for body in one time?

```
body {
    background-color: #AAA;
background: url(../images/foto.jpg) no-repeat bottom right; 
}
```

Background-color works only if I remove background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here is an example:

```
body {
  background: #aaa
  url(../images/foto.jpg) no-repeat
  bottom right;
}
```